# Resizing mat openCV in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

In c++, Visual Studio, I have image

```
cv::Mat EnergyImage;
```

which is 2D with dimension of 2x6000000

I want to convert it to 2 image with size of 200x300x100(=6000000), better to say two 3d images.

how can I reshape it and access to 2 image seprately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV provides the `cv::Mat` constructor API where you can create an n-dimensional Matrix with arbitrary bins in each dimension as:

```
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat(1, 6000000, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(100));

int sizes[3] = {200, 300, 100};
cv::Mat multiDimMat = cv::Mat(3, sizes, CV_8UC1, &m.data[0]);
```

The above code would suffice if you had linear `cv::Mat` with only one row, but since your input `cv::Mat` has 2 rows and you want 2 separate `cv::Mat` objects for each row, you may try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < m.rows; i++)
{
    const uchar* mi = m.ptr<uchar>(i);
    // Perform the same routine as above code 
}
```

Comment: But how can I resize it? by this for loop I have 1x6000000 argument. But how can I resize it to 200x300x100 ?

Comment: I access to each row more easily, cv:: Mat mi1 = EnergyImage.row(1);
cv:: Mat mi0 = EnergyImage.row(0);
this 2 vector has 1x6000000 dimension. I think I didn't write my question clearly, I just want to resize(or reshape) this vector to 3d mat.